# Adempiere Business Partner Location Tab Class Name

Tags: class, adempiere

What is the Class Name of Location Tab of Business Partner in which its save button methods  are resides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To save the record in location dialog

  For ZK version `org.adempiere.webui.window.WLocationDialog`
  For swing verion `org.compiere.grid.ed.VLocationDialog`

For location of the business partner logic `org.compiere.model.MBPartnerLocation`